# How should I reliably mark the most recent row in SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

The existing design for this program is that all changes are written to a changelog table with a timestamp. In order to obtain the current state of an item's attribute we `JOIN` onto the changelog table and take the row having the most recent timestamp.

This is a messy way to keep track of current values, but we cannot readily change this changelog setup at this time.

I intend to slightly modify the behavior by adding an "IsMostRecent" bit to the changelog table. This would allow me to simply pull the row having that bit set, as opposed to the `MAX()` aggregation or recursive seek.

What strategy would you employ to make sure that bit is always appropriately set? Or is there some alternative you suggest which doesn't affect the current use of the logging table?

Currently I am considering a trigger approach, which turns the bit off all other rows, and then turns it on for the most recent row on an `INSERT`

Comment: Do you have more reads or inserts? which is more time sensitive?

Comment: @bendataclear I have roughly 10 times as many reads as inserts, but the real pain point here is in when I want to do aggregations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Started this answer before Richard Harrison answered, promise :)

I would suggest another table with the structure similar to below:

```
VersionID  TableName   UniqueVal  LatestPrimaryKey
1          Orders      209        12548
2          Orders      210        12549
3          Orders      211        12605
4          Orders      212        10694

VersionID -- being the tables key
TableName -- just in case you want to roll out to multiple tables
UniqueVal -- is whatever groups multiple rows into a single item with history (eg Order Number or some other value)
LatestPrimaryKey -- is the identity key of the latest row you want to use.
```

Then you can simply `JOIN` to this table to return only the latest rows.

If you already have a trigger inserting rows into the changelog table this could be adapted:

```
INSERT INTO [MyChangelogTable]
(Primary, RowUpdateTime)
VALUES (@PrimaryKey, GETDATE())

-- Add onto it:

UPDATE [LatestRowTable]
SET [LatestPrimaryKey] = @PrimaryKey
WHERE [TableName] = 'Orders'
AND [UniqueVal] = @OrderNo
```

Alternatively it could be done as a merge to capture inserts as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this before by having a "MostRecentRecorded" table which simply has the most recently inserted record (Id and entity ID) fired off a trigger.

Having an extra column for this isn't right - and can get you into problems with transactions and reading existing entries.

In the first version of this it was a simple case of

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    INSERT INTO simlog (entityid, logmessage) 
           VALUES     (11, 'test'); 

    UPDATE simlogmostrecent 
    SET    lastid = @@IDENTITY 
    WHERE  simlogentityid = 11 
COMMIT
```

Ensuring that the MostRecent table had an entry for each record in SimLog can be done in the query but ISTR we did it during the creation of the entity that the SimLog referred to (the above is my recollection of the first version - I don't have the code to hand).

However the simple version caused problems with multiple writers as could cause a deadlock or transaction failure; so it was moved into a trigger.

Comment: So this is a table with one column (or so) that FK's to the changelog. I simply `JOIN` onto from my changelog to determine current state? This is doable, how has it worked in practice for you with aggregations? You trigger on your log `INSERT`s do an atomic `DELETE` / `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to your "MostRecentRecorded" table?

Comment: initially inline in the SQL - but eventually into a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind is to create a view to do all the messy MAX() queries, etc. behind the scenes.  Then you should be able to query against the view.  This way would not have to change your current setup, just move all the messiness to one place.

Comment: It obfuscates the current mess, but the SQL is not intimidating. The problem I'm trying to mitigate here is the recursive seek behavior when I need aggregated information. a View doesn't solve that problem, it arguably makes it worse.